# Combine 2 string columns in pandas with different conditions in both columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 columns in pandas, with data that looks like this.

```
code fx         category
AXD  AXDG.R     cat1
AXF  AXDG_e.FE  cat1 
333  333.R      cat1
....
```

There are other categories but I am only interested in cat1.

I want to combine everything from the `code` column, and everything after the `.` in the `fx` column and replace the code column with the new combination without affecting the other rows.

```
code    fx         category
AXD.R   AXDG.R     cat1
AXF.FE  AXDG_e.FE  cat1
333.R   333.R      cat1
.....
```

Here is my code, I think I have to use regex but I'm not sure how to combine it in this way.

```
df.loc[df['category']== 'cat1', 'code'] = df[df['category'] == 'cat1']['code'].str.replace(r'[a-z](?=\.)', '', regex=True).str.replace(r'_?(?=\.)','', regex=True).str.replace(r'G(?=\.)', '', regex=True)
```

I'm not sure how to select the second column also. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There are other categories but I am only interested in cat1

You can use `str.split` with `series.where` to add the extention for cat1:

```
df['code'] = (df['code'].astype(str).add("."+df['fx'].str.split(".").str[-1])
             .where(df['category'].eq("cat1"),df['code']))
```

---

```
print(df)

     code         fx category
0   AXD.R     AXDG.R     cat1
1  AXF.FE  AXDG_e.FE     cat1
2   333.R      333.R     cat1
```

Comment: I am getting this error, TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str', I am guessing some rows might have digits? is that possible?

Comment: @anarchy you probably have mixed datatypes in your series. Convert to string first using `df['code']=df['code'].astype(str)` and then try.

Comment: yeah I actually figured it out haha, added the as type and it works.. thanks!

Comment: I updated your answer to include the string conversion

Answer (score 3):

You can `extract` the part of `fx` and append it to `code`:

```
df['code'] += df['fx'].str.extract('(\..*$)')[0]
```

output:

```
     code         fx category
0   AXD.R     AXDG.R     cat1
1  AXF.FE  AXDG_e.FE     cat1
2   333.R      333.R     cat1
```

to limit to `cat1` only:

```
df.loc[df['category'].eq('cat1'), 'code'] += df['fx'].str.extract('(\..*$)')[0]
```

Comment: Can you explain the \..*$ part?

Comment: @anarchy match a literal dot `\.` followed by a series of characters `.*` and end of line `$`.

Comment: I thought there only needs to be one dot though, what’s the second one for

Comment: An unescaped dot means "any character" in a regex.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['code'] = df['code'].astype(str) + np.where(df['category'].eq('cat1'), df['fx'].astype(str).str.extract('(\..+)')[0], '')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     code         fx category
0   AXD.R     AXDG.R     cat1
1  AXF.FE  AXDG_e.FE     cat1
2   333.R      333.R     cat1
```

Answer (score 2):

We can get the expected result using [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) like so :

```py
>>> df['code'] = df['code'] + '.' + df['fx'].str.split(pat=".", expand=True)[1]
>>> df
    code    fx          category    
0   AXD.R   AXDG.R      cat1        
1   AXF.FE  AXDG_e.FE   cat1        
2   333.R   333.R       cat1
```

To filter only on `cat1`, as @anky did very well, we can add a `where` statement:

```py
>>> df['code'] = (df['code'] + '.' + df['fx'].str.split(pat=".", expand=True)[1]).where(df['category'].eq("cat1"), df['code'])
```

Comment: what about filtering 'cat1' only ?

Comment: Indeed ! I updated my answer to filter on `cat1` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Replace alphanumerics before the dot. Append the result to column code.

```
df['code'] +=df['fx'].str.replace('(^[\w]+(?=\.))','',regex=True)




    code         fx  category
0   AXD.R     AXDG.R     cat1
1  AXF.FE  AXDG_e.FE     cat1
2   333.R      333.R     cat1
```